# Layout Problems with tabularx and mathmode

Tags: math-mode, tabularx, multirow, multicolumn

I have a problem with a specific tabularx I'm using in my master thesis.

I produced this code:

```
\documentclass[headsepline,titlepage,oneside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|C|*{6}{C|}}\firsthline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Integrationsart}  &   \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Berechnung}   &   \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries Skala (0 - 5)}\\\cline{3-8}
                                                &                                           &   0   &   1   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5\\\hline
    Datenintegration                    &   $BK2 + BK5_{admin. Anmeld.} + BK5_{Abrechnung}$ & $>$8 & 7 - 8 & 5 - 6 & 3 - 4 & 1 - 2 & 0\\\hline
    Prozessintegration                  &   $BK4_{admin. Anmeld.} + BK4_{Abrechnung} + BK5_{admin. Anmeld.} + BK5_{Abrechnung}$ & $>$10 & 9 - 10 & 7 - 8 & 5 - 6 & 3 - 4 & $\leq$2\\\hline
    \end{tabularx}

\caption{Abbildung der Wertebereiche der Bewertungskriterien auf die Skala der Integrationsqualitäten}
\label{tab:BKtoSpider}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

but the PDF layout comes out like this:
[image: PDF layout of tabularx table]

I have no idea why the Skala columns are much wider than the numbers within and why the column "Berechnung" has no space.

Any ideas?

I thank you guys for your time and I'm looking forward to your suggestions for my first question on this platform. ;-)

Peter

Comment: What's with your rush to accept the first answer almost as soon as it's posted? On this site, it's generally recommended to wait a few hours before accepting one of the answers. Otherwise, you'll seriously risk discourage others from posting a competing answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that advice. I just tried and liked it, didn't know I can't accept more than one answer. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Holene. Didn't know the documentclass and begin-end document is necessary, but it totally makes sence since it's just a copy&paste for helpers to have an eye on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified a width, but the content was too wide. You do not want `tabularx` for data tables, it is designed for controlling line breaks in tables of *text*. Also never use math italic for multi-letter words.

Something like this, although it may be too wide, you gave no indication of your page size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

    \begin{tabular}{|l|>{\centering}p{3cm}|*{6}{c|}}\firsthline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Integrationsart}  &  
 \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Berechnung}   &   \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries Skala (0 - 5)}\\\cline{3-8}
                                                &                                           &   0   &   1   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5\\\hline
    Datenintegration                    &   $BK2 + BK5_{\textrm{admin. Anmeld.}} + BK5_{\textrm{Abrechnung}}$ & $>$8 & 7 - 8 & 5 - 6 & 3 - 4 & 1 - 2 & 0\\\hline
    Prozessintegration                  &   $BK4_{\textrm{admin. Anmeld.}} + BK4_{\textrm{Abrechnung}} + BK5_{\textrm{admin. Anmeld.}} + BK5_{\textrm{Abrechnung}}$ & $>$10 & 9 - 10 & 7 - 8 & 5 - 6 & 3 - 4 & $\leq$2\\\hline
    \end{tabular}

\caption{Abbildung der Wertebereiche der Bewertungskriterien auf die Skala der Integrationsqualitäten}
\label{tab:BKtoSpider}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you, David! I'll figure out the little sizing know...

Comment: There's a good chance that this table will be quite a bit wider than the text block.

Comment: As I configurate the widths of the Skala columns, I found out I can't use `*{6}{>{\centering}m{0.9cm}`, just `*{6}{m{0.9cm}`. Do you know why I can't use `>{\centering}` in the multiple column definition?

Comment: Have you missed out a `}` (you have in the code fragment in the comment)

Comment: ah, no. That was a c&p error. :-P

Comment: @Peter impossible to say then, unless you show the tex error. oh unless that 6 includes the last column in which case you want `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` or use `\tabularnewline` rather than `\\ ` to end table rows

Comment: @Mico all those long German words, you should do something about that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I did, in my answer: I added `\hyphenation{inte-gra-tionsart daten-integra-tion prozess-integra-tion}`. :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: yes, the `\arraybackslash` was the missing part. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with a `tabularx` setup, you need to widen the second column and reduce the widths of columns 3 to 8. (Calculation hint: 2.6+6*0.7333=7= # of columns whose width is either being increased or decreased.)

You also need to break up the long quasi-math expressions in the second column so that LateX can actually insert linebreaks. You also need to do something about the first column so that hyphenation is permissible on the first (and, as it turns out, only) words in each cell; I suggest you insert `\hspace{0pt}` for this purpose. Talking about hyphenation, it's probably also a good idea to load the `babel` package and provide a few more hyphenation points.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,amsbsy}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\hyphenation{inte-gra-tionsart daten-integra-tion prozess-integra-tion}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}%
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}%

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|>{\hsize=2.6\hsize}L|*{6}{>{\hsize=0.7333\hsize}C|}}
\firsthline
\bfseries Integrationsart  &   \bfseries Berechnung   &   \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\bfseries Skala (0 -- 5)}\\
\cline{3-8}
 & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
 \hline
Datenintegration  &   
BK2 $+$ 
BK5$_{\text{admin. Anmeld.}}$ $+$ 
BK5$_{\text{Abrechnung}}$ & 
$>8$ & 7 -- 8 & 5 -- 6 & 3 -- 4 & 1 -- 2 & 0\\
\hline
Prozessintegration&   
BK4$_{\text{admin. Anmeld.}}$ $+$ 
BK4$_{\text{Abrechnung}}$ $+$ 
BK5$_{\text{admin. Anmeld.}}$ $+$ 
BK5$_{\text{Abrechnung}}$ & 
$>10 $& 9 -- 10 & 7 -- 8 & 5 -- 6 & 3 -- 4 & $\leq2$\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Abbildung der Wertebereiche der Bewertungskriterien auf die Skala der Integrationsqualitäten}
\label{tab:BKtoSpider}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, posted after the OP indicated that the `report` document class is in use: It's probably a good idea not to allow line breaks in the words in the first column. Switching the column type from `L` to `l` and getting rid of all vertical bars and employing the rule-drawing macros of the [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package produces the following, more "open" look for the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[headsepline,titlepage,oneside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,amsbsy,mathtools}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l >{\hsize=2.6\hsize}L *{6}{>{\hsize=0.7333\hsize}C} @{}}
\toprule
Integrationsart & Berechnung & \multicolumn{6}{c@{}}{Skala (0--5)}\\
\cmidrule(l){3-8}
 & & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\midrule
Datenintegration  &   
BK2\,$+$ 
BK5$_{\text{admin. Anmeld.}}$\,$+$ 
BK5$_{\text{Abrechnung}}$ & 
$>$8 & 7--8 & 5--6 & 3--4 & 1--2 & 0\\
\addlinespace
Prozessintegration&   
BK4$_{\text{admin. Anmeld.}}$\,$+$ 
BK4$_{\text{Abrechnung}}$\,$+$ 
BK5$_{\text{admin. Anmeld.}}$\,$+$ 
BK5$_{\text{Abrechnung}}$ & 
$>$10& 9--10 & 7--8 & 5--6 & 3--4 & $\leq$2\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Abbildung der Wertebereiche der Bewertungskriterien 
auf die Skala der Integrationsqualitäten}
\label{tab:BKtoSpider}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```